# Generic method that returns typed values

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

I need to write a method in Java something like this:

```
<T> getProperty(String key, T defaultValue) {
     final Object value = this.config.getProperty(key); 
     return value == null ? defaultValue : (T) value;
}
```

However the (T) value will be throwing for almost anything. Say I want to read the property 'enabled' as boolean, it would be throwing an exception 'Cannot cast from String to Boolean'. I am looking for Convert.ChangeType that we have in C#.

Is there a way?

Comment: What if the property is a String and you want a boolean? Can't just convert those two. Also, did you mean to use `propertyName` instead of `key` in your snippet?

Comment: Yeah, it was 'key' in the snippet. Have corrected it. Yeah the property value is always a string (I dont know why it is returned as a object) but I would like to convert it to the type I request. So I would say getProperty("enable", false), and get the string value defined ("true" or "false") as boolean.

Comment: There's no such global conversion mechanism in java. You can make your own, but you'll have to consider every type (ever class).

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to create a type converter yourself and use it.

Eg.

```
Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Converter c = new Converter();

<T> T getProperty( String propertyName, T defaultValue ) {
    final Object value = this.config.get( propertyName );
    return value == null ? defaultValue : ( T ) c.convert( value, defaultValue.getClass() );
}

class Converter {

    <T> T convert( Object value, Class<T> targetClass ) {
        if ( targetClass.equals( Boolean.class ) ) {
            if ( value.equals( "true" ) )
                return ( T ) Boolean.TRUE;
            else
                return ( T ) Boolean.FALSE;
        } else if ( targetClass.equals( String.class ) ) {
            return ( T ) value.toString();
        }
        // add more type-specific converters here
        return ( T ) value; // no type-specific converters, just trying our luck
    }
```

Or, to keep type-safety, replace the last return with:

```
if ( value.getClass().isAssignableFrom( targetClass ) )
            return ( T ) value; // no type-specific converters, but cast is safe
        else
            throw new ClassCastException( value.getClass().getName()
                     + " cannot be cast to " + targetClass.getName() );
```